# How to create bitcoin wallet for many users?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

I need create bitcoin wallet for many users but I have no idea how to do it.
Before that I thought to do it with bitcoin-core. But it turned out that accounts are not what I need. In the new version (v.0.15.0) of the bitcoin-core there are multi-wallets, but to add a new wallet it is necessary to restart the daemon.
Who can tell me?

Answer (score 1):

To manage many users balances, you should generate a new deposit address for each person, and keep track of their balances via your own database or similar, rather than relying on the deprecated account system in bitcoin core.

Comment: Do you mean I should for each users generate private key, then get public key and then get address from public key? I mean generate addresses without bitcoin-core and _accounts_?

Comment: Yes you can use the `getnewaddress` RPC